# How to Build Questions and Answer in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently, I have no idea **what is the best approach to sending information from one button to another in Unity**.

For example, if you select tripping, it may have 2 questions and answers, while Tripping Flow Check may have 3 questions and 3 answers.  Tripping Shut-In may only have 1 question and 1 answer but the answer could be a jpg file, etc.

The image at the bottom is the current setup but **don't know how to set it programmatically** in Unity.  Any recommendation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically you need to create a script where you reference different UI elements and change them when you want and as you want.

You can communicate easily between your UI elements, gameObjects and scripts using `Events`. Thanks to Unity Events you can do it from the inspector.

For instance this way you can disable/enable another object with your button:

[image]

This way you can change the UI Text.text

[image]

You can call methods from your scripts exactly the same way. Simply drag the object you want to interact with to On Click() tab, find the script you want in the drop down menu and select the method you want to invoke.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, but currently, I'm using the same technique.  The problem is, there are 40 of these Q&A and it gets real messes.  I'm looking for a cleaner solution if possible.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Try to write and draw an algorithm first. It should help you plan your script logic. Check if there are any similar algorithms and how to implement them. Split your script so smaller chunks to make it more readable, manageable and understandable. Sorry if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Understandable Dave, I didn't really specify my technique.  I was planning to upload another jpg image to show you what I'm currently doing but don't know how to link an image back on this comment.  Basically, I have each question and answer display as a jpg image.   Once you press Q1, an image file will pop up.  I did the same thing with the Answer.  You are asking why I'm using a images file vs text.  It has to do with Unity text formatting.  I can't get unity to create bullets point and return line correctly.

Comment: You can edit your question and add jpg. It will help others to answer your questions.

Comment: How do you add jpg to my comment?  I don't see the options to do so.

Comment: It is not possible to add jpg to comments here.

Comment: Thanks.  That what I thought.